# Glossy and no reflection - only shadow

Tags: materials, node-editor

[image]

Hi. I have square and ball. Square is Glossy BSDF material, and ball is only ball. I have no reflection in square and it is problem. I want reflection effect.

Comment: Cycles, right? Are lights involved in this scene? If yes, where is it located?

Comment: Cycles. Lights is hemi for some time, but if i disable hemi and create point light opposite mirror then is the same. I want mirror effect but i get shadow in mirror.

Comment: Without checking the blend file directly, I don't think this is shadow, but I think this is because the back part of the sphere is not enlighted

Comment: I create new project, append this mirror and work good.

Comment: But still i have problem in primary project

Comment: I have solution. Enter the value more than 0 in "Render tab" and tab "light paths" and "Glossy" more than 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like amount of light bounces for Glossy rays in your scene under the [Light Paths](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/settings/light_paths.html) rollout is set to 0 and looks like this:

[image: screenshot of black reflection]

This will make Cycles not to take into account rays which bounced from camera to the surface with only Glossy shader (e.g. plane supposed to be the floor also has glossy added to material nodes but it's mixed with Diffuse shader and Fresnel as the factor, so blackish reflection will be visible under certain angle).

Increase bounces to something more than 0, 8 by default and glossy reflections should appear.

---

Another possibility - *Clamp Indirect* under Sampling rollout is set to something really slow, like 0.0001. Then any reflections in the scene will be also black.

[image: screenshot of black refl-2]

These values depend on the scene but generally you don't want them to be less than 1.